# Resize views relative to each other Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout, interface-builder

I am building a new app using Xcode 6 and auto layout. I have only just started using auto layout and this maybe a really simple issue to fix but i have been going around in circles trying to find the right way.

I have a view played out as follows (don't have the rep to post images so have used a link instead)

http://files.parsetfss.com/48d8d860-e1c2-4671-ac59-03f46eee316b/tfss-23f6bdb8-3e5b-4ce0-b7ed-b1daf0006f33-Screen%20Shot%202015-05-22%20at%202.56.03%20pm.png

I have set constraints on the red box to keep its left,right and bottom the same distance from the superview and another to keep its height the same at all times. I then set constraints on the black and green box's keeping there top and out side edges the same distance from the superview and there bottom edges the same distance from the red box.

The aim is that the red box stays the same height and changes width with the device size and orientation, With the green and black changing height and width to fill half of the rest of the screen each and meet in the middle.

Now i have set constraints to keep the black and green the same distance from each other, and it worked as i wanted however i get warnings that the black and green boxes have ambiguous positions and widths.

The only way i have come up with to get rid of the warnings is to place a label (alpha set to 0 so it can't be seen) that is constrained to the centre of the screen then set the black and green box's contains based on the label. This works and is warning free but i am sure that this is not the best way around the issue.

So the question is how do i do this with out errors and with out placing an unnecessary hidden label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the view at the bottom has a fixed height...you just need to pin all edges of the all views and just need to give equal width constraints to the black and green views...just like below image...

[image]

And the output in different screens...

[image]

Comment: I knew it would be simple! Thank you so much.

Comment: Would love to up vote but i don't have 15 rep yet :-(

Comment: Ok...no problem..happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the black and green boxes an "equal widths" constraint. Select both boxes, and choose "Equal Widths" from the pin icon at the bottom of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements

**1 view Black:** 
[image: 1view]

**2 view Green:** 
[image: 2view]

**3 view Red:** 
[image: 3view]

Follow these links [Autolayout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/) or [Autolayout programatically](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)

This might helps you :)